# How to get image at navbar in python django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

I am not getting images at my navbar although I  am giving the source to it,please give the actual code.

`<img src="{%  static 'AARTHA/images/logo.jpeg' %}">`

**Here is the folder structure in Pycharm :-**

[image]

Comment: how do you handle static files in your `settings.py`?

Comment: by this command STATIC_URL='/static/'

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `static` folder in your app, and it should look something like this. By the way, `AARATHA` under static folder, should be directory not python module:

```
<your_app_name>/static/<your_app_name>/images/logo.jpeg
```

Also, don't forget to load static files at the beginning of templates by:

```
{% load static %}
```

---

Alternative would be adding `STATICFILES_DIR` without changing path of static folder, which will take care of not-in-app static files:

```
STATIC_URL='/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
    ]
```